# Convergence of Fourier integral

Tags: integration

I have noticed that the Fourier integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathscr{F}f(\omega) e^{i\omega t} d\omega $ of $f(t) = \mu(t) e^{-t}$, where $\mathscr{F}f(\omega) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) e^{-i\omega t} dt$ and $\mu(t)$ is the step function diverges at $t = 0$. Is there a beautiful notation using the Riemann-integral that fixes the problem? Here I mean the improper Riemann-integral of the first kind. I have considered the operator pair
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathscr{F}f(\omega) & = & \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^\infty (f(t) e^{-i\omega t} + f(-t) e^{i\omega t}) dt \\
\mathscr{F}'F(t) & = & \int_0^\infty (F(\omega) e^{i\omega t} + F(-\omega) e^{-i\omega t}) d\omega \ ,
\end{eqnarray}
that is defined for functions $f$ that satisfy i) $\mathscr{F}f$ exists everywhere, ii) $\mathscr{F}' \mathscr{F}f$ exists everywhere, iii) $\mathscr{F}' \mathscr{F} f = f$. The Cauchy principal value would be ideal, but I don't quite like the notation P.V. in front of the integral and it might allow functions to satisfy all conditions without being locally bounded. The limit form $\lim_{M \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-M}^M f(x) dx$ isn't good either because it isn't notationally optimal for applications. I mean that for example the formula $De^x = e^x$ is simple but $D \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \big(1+\frac{x}{n}\big)^n = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \big(1+\frac{x}{n}\big)^n$ is a little more complicated. I would want to find good expressions for Fourier and inverse Fourier transform that exist everywhere for some important functions familiar from signal processing including $\chi_{[-1,1]}(x)$ and $\textrm{sinc}(x)$.

Comment: Sorry, what is the question?

Comment: Is there a beautiful notation using the Riemann-integral that fixes the problem?

Comment: I guess I did not understand what the problem is.

Comment: The problem is that the imaginary part $\frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{-\omega}{1+\omega^2}$ of $\mathscr{F}f$, where $f(t)=\mu(t)e^{-t}$ causes the Fourier integral to diverge at $0$ with the conventional definitions of transform and inverse transform.

Answer (score 1):

I think you end up defining $f(t)=1/2$ for $t=0$.  I will explain why below.

$$\hat{f}(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dt \, f(t) \, e^{i \omega t} = \frac{1}{1-i \omega}$$

To recover $f(t)$, use the inverse transform:

$$\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\omega \, \frac{e^{-i \omega t}}{1-i \omega}$$

Consider the following integral in the complex plane:

$$\oint_C dz \, \frac{e^{-i z t}}{1-i z}$$

When $t>0$, $C$ is a positively oriented semicircular contour in the lower half plane of radius $R$.  The integral about the circular arc vanishes as $R \to \infty$.  The integral over $C$ is $i 2 \pi$ times the residue at the pole at $z=-i$:

$$-\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\omega \, \frac{e^{-i \omega t}}{1-i \omega} = \frac{i 2 \pi}{2 \pi i} e^{-i (-i) t} = e^{-t}$$

When $t<0$, $C$ is a semicircular contour in the upper half plane.  Since there are no poles there, the integral there is zero.

When $t=0$, neither contour leads to convergence.  In this case, we impose a sort of "analytic" continuation at $t=0$, even though we make no pretense at continuity at $t=0$.  Rather, we impose the condition that

$$f(0) = \frac12 [f(0^-) + f(0^+)]$$

where $f(0^-)=0$ and $f(0^+)=1$.  This then allows us to write $f(t)=\mu(t) e^{-t}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I have noticed also that the inverse transform should converge to $1/2$ at $0$. There is however a problem with the definition of integral because the integral of the imaginary part $\frac{\omega}{1+\omega^2}$ diverges. Now even the Lebesgue integral doesn't help. So I thougth to define the transform with a special expression.

Comment: So I thought to define the transform-inverse transform pair with special expressions. Note that by linearity we may analyze the imaginary part alone. Define now $f(\omega) = \frac{\omega}{1+\omega^2}$. Then $\mathscr{F}'f(0) = \int_0^\infty 0 d\omega = 0$.

Comment: For the real part $f(\omega) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{1}{1+\omega^2}$ $\mathscr{F}'f(0) = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{2}{1+\omega^2} d\omega = \frac{1}{2}$. Yet corrections to the previous comments. The imaginary part equals to $\frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{\omega}{1+\omega^2}$. That's because of the definition of Fourier transform in our Complex analysis book "Complex Analysis for Mathematics and Engineering".

Comment: @Juha-MattiVihtanen: when confronted with a situation like this, a divergence at one point, I like to impose "continuity" in a Fourier sense.  Think of it as some sort of analytic continuation.

Comment: It seems to me that we miss a minus sign. The transform $\mathscr{F}f(\omega) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{1}{i+\omega}$ and its imaginary part is $\frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{-\omega}{1+\omega^2}$ using the definitions above that are equivalent to the definitions in my Comlpex nalysis book..

Comment: I prefer a special expression instead. That's because analytic continuation has to do with connected sets and assumes the existence of complex derivative, that isn't true in this situation.

Comment: @Juha-MattiVihtanen: I disagree, and note that I was very careful about signs (also note the term, "positively-oriented").  The minus sign in front of the integral in the penultimate equation (to keep positive orientation below the real axis) is canceled by the factor of $-i$ in the denominator.

Comment: In my Complex analysis book the minus sign in the forward transform came from that in the expression of Fourier coefficients.

Comment: @Juha-MattiVihtanen: I think you and I are speaking of different things.

Comment: There was an error left to $\frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{1}{i+\omega}$. It should be $\frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{1}{1+i\omega}$.

Comment: I prefer to have a convergent expression and show afterwards that a function satisfying $\mathscr{F}'\mathscr{F}f = f$ satisfies also $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}(\lim_{t \rightarrow x^+} f(t) + \lim_{t \rightarrow x^-} f(t))$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ provided that the limits exist.